# How to get first name and last name when last name is multiple names in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and need to separate first and last name. So far this is where I got to.

```
df = [['Victor De La Cruz', 'Ashley Smith', 'Angel Miguel Hernandez', 'Hank Hill']] 

df['first_name'] = df.str.split().str[0]
df['last_name'] = df.str.split().str[1:]
```

OutPut

```
first_name        last_name 
 Victor           [De, La, Cruz]
 Ashley           [Smith] 
 Angel            [Miguel, Hernandez]
 Hank             [Hill]
```

I have tried using `df'last_name'].replace('[', '')`for all characters not wanted but it didn't work.

Desired Output

```
 first_name      last_name 
   Paul          De La Cruz 
   Ashley        Smith 
   Angel         Miguel Hernandez
   Hank          Hill
```

Any Suggestions would be helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join back

```
df['last_name'] = df['last_name'].str.join(' ')
```

After the `split()`, you have list objects in your series, not strings, which is why `.replace()` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the `n` keyword argument to limit the splits to only the first space. You could also use `expand=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    'Victor De La Cruz',
    'Ashley Smith',
    'Angel Miguel Hernandez',
    'Hank Hill'
])

df = s.str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ["first_name", "last_name"]
```

```
  first_name         last_name
0     Victor        De La Cruz
1     Ashley             Smith
2      Angel  Miguel Hernandez
3       Hank              Hill
```